XSLT Variable assigning for each incremental delimiter position from the input XML
For the Input XML:
<EmpJob>
    <EmpJob>
        <ConcatDepartment>+Local_Functions+Group_Functions+Group_Owners+Group_Managers+Group_Leads+Interim_Services</ConcatDepartment>
    </EmpJob>
</EmpJob>

I want to have the values assigned to the variables like below in my XSLT.  Delimiter is + and it should increment while assiging the values to each department variables in the XSLT so that I can use them get the below expected output ..
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[1]" /> should return the string "" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[2]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[3]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions/Group_Functions" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[4]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[5]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[6]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers/Group_Leads" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[7]" /> should return the string "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers/Group_Leads/Interim_Services" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[8]" /> should return the string "" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[9]" /> should return the string "" 
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[10]" /> should return the string "" 

I tried with
<xsl:variable name="departments" select="tokenize(/EmpJob/EmpJob/ConcatDepartment, '\+')"/>

<xsl:value-of select="$departments[1]" />

is returning the string ""
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[2]" /> 

is returning the string "Local_Functions"
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[3]" /> 

is returning the string "Group_Functions"
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[4]" /> 

is returning the string "Group_Owners" and so on...Any help woth the XSLT will be really helpful

Please don't spam tags if your actual problem isn't related to [tag:xslt1.0] and [tag:xslt2.0] and [tag:xslt3.0] all at once.

Well, one example is not a spec of what you want to achieve. What would happen with e.g. <ConcatDepartment>+Local_Functions+Group_Functions+Group_Owners+Group_Managers+Group_Leads+Interim_Services++Foo</ConcatDepartment>?

the requirement is to create rows for a CSV file like below from the source input XML
Line1, ""
Line2, "Local_Functions"
Line3, "Local_Functions/Group_Functions"
Line4, "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners"
Line5, "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers"
Line6, "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers/Group_Leads"
Line7, "Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers/Group_Leads/Interim_Services"

@Filburt Please do not remove ALL the tags relating to the version. Pavan Kumar: Always tag your questions with the version of XSLT that your processor supports  - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153.

To get the behavior you want, use an expression like:
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[position() le 4]" separator="/"/>

to return the string:
/Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners

Note that the expression:
<xsl:value-of select="$departments[position() le 10]" separator="/"/>

will return:
/Local_Functions/Group_Functions/Group_Owners/Group_Managers/Group_Leads/Interim_Services

and not an empty string. I am not sure what is the  logic that should be used to produce the exact results you show.

Added:
To get a result like the one shown in your comment, do something like:
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/EmpJob">
    <xsl:variable name="departments" select="tokenize(EmpJob/ConcatDepartment, '\+')"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($departments)">
        <xsl:text>Line</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>,"</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$departments[position() le current()]" separator="/"/>
        <xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>

